# Magento2 exception during installation: 'LogicException' with message 'Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData'

Tags: magento2, error, installation, sample-data

I got this error while installing Magento2

> ```
> [ERROR] exception 'LogicException' with message 'Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData'' in setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:403
> Stack trace:
> #0 setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(364): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array, 'enable_modules') 
> #1 setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(323): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array) 
> #2 setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(97): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) 
> #3 vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() 
> #4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
> #5 vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
> #6 vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
> #7 vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
> #8 vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) 
> #9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
> #10 vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
> #11 vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
> #12 vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) 
> #13 setup\index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() 
> #14 {main}
> ```

---

Also see this screenshot:

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: What is Magento2 version you install ?

Comment: 2.0, no samples

Comment: Are you download it from Github ?

Comment: Now I have been successful by command line. But when i login the backend have a prompt that "Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in E:\www\magento2g\app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\system\search.phtml on line 31"

Comment: I am getting this same error on Nexcess when trying to install a fresh version from the web interface

Comment: Are you missing a PHP requirement like "--enable-intl" in your PHP 5.5 or higher version? I've seen that cause odd errors in Magento 2 installs...

Comment: We're tracking it as an open issue on github - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2891

Comment: @Jeffery did you have a previous installation? is your database clean?

Comment: Also, clean browser cache.

Comment: Change of the browser and after try to install

Answer (score 21):

Most of the time these type of errors come when you try to install magento2 previously and it was failed due to some reason.

and you have started your installation process again after removing all of the previous installed files and removed old database entry.

So, to overcome this issue, before starting your installation process, just remove your browser's cookie.

Enjoy :)

Comment: You're the hero of the day. Who stores that in a cookie...?!? Thanks!

Comment: Magento is absolutely pathetic sometimes, seriously!

Answer (score 6):

Clear the cache of your browser. It's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

From `Customize Your Store` step in `Advanced Modules Configurations`, Uncheck `'Magento_SampleBundleData'` and continue on to install. I was stuck with the same error so moved back to the step and unchecked the module.

Also check that you've your browser cache cleaned. 
This was on version (magento ce)2.0.2

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart the server, mysql and check,

and remove the browser cookies to

Refer this link : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_bundlesampledata.html

Answer (score 2):

I  got same error while I was installing Magento 2.3.4

I just opened incognito mode in chrome and, then I tried to install again and then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser cache and cookies OR just use some other browser. I was facing the same issue. I just used Mozilla Firefox instead of Google Chrome and all fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and after that I tried to install with Firefox which worked perfectly and no need to do any thing.

```
 Try With Firefox Browser.
```

Comment: Seemed a bit weird to me, but it worked, Thank you.

Comment: @Seemed you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restart your mysql in this case.

```
sudo service mysql restart
 * Stopping MySQL Community Server 5.6.30
....
 * MySQL Community Server 5.6.30 is stopped
 * Re-starting MySQL Community Server 5.6.30
......
 * MySQL Community Server 5.6.30 is started
```

if it still does not work fine, please restart apache2 also:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```