# Magento 2 : Installation issue in magento2.x (ver 2.0.70)

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-2.0.7

I am trying to install new Magento 2 version of 2.0.7 and getting this error in last step in installation.

```
[ERROR] exception 'LogicException' with message 'Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData'' in /var/www/html/magento2_7/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:417
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2_7/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(378): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array, 'enable_modules')
#1 /var/www/html/magento2_7/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(325): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento2_7/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(103): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/html/magento2_7/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/html/magento2_7/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Apache And Mysql

centos :

```
         systemctl restart httpd
         systemcrtl restart mysqld
```

ubuntu  :

```
         service apache2 restart 
         service mysql restart
```

Then Check it.

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2944

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2891

[Magento2 exception during installation: 'LogicException' with message 'Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92582/magento2-exception-during-installation-logicexception-with-message-unknown-m)